# InfoPath Form User Restriction

Tags: infopath

I have an InfoPath form that submits to a library. I want to restrict user from submitting the form data the second time after the first submission.

Comment: How about you store values entered by the user in variables. And have a formatting rule to check if values in the controls are the same as those in your variables. If they are, the submit button is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a check box. Make a rule for submit button to check this check box after submitting. And another rule for submit button to hide itself if check box value is true.